# Searching of messages from inbox is not successful

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I want to get the information about the messages from the inbox on the basis of a particular number.I am using following code for achieving the goal but it is not working in the expected way:

```
public void SendTheSmsToTheFolder(String NameOfContact,String Number,String FolderAddress,long TimeLimit)
    {
        m_NameOfContact = NameOfContact;
        String SMS_URI_INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; 
        Uri l_uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX); 

        Cursor l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor = getContentResolver().query(l_uri, null, "address=?",new         String[]{Number.trim()},null);
        if (l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.moveToFirst())
        {  
            int l_index_Address = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getColumnIndex("address");  
            int l_index_Person = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getColumnIndex("person");  
            int l_index_Body = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getColumnIndex("body");  
            int l_index_Date = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getColumnIndex("date");  
            do 
            {  
                String l_strAddress = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getString(l_index_Address);  
                String l_strbody = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getString(l_index_Body);  
                long l_longDate = l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.getLong(l_index_Date);  

                Log.v("Message: ","Body of the message is "+l_strbody);
            } while (l_SendTheSmsToTheFolderCursor.moveToNext());  
        }
}
```

I am quite sure that the message having that particular phone number is present in the box and i have cross checked this fact.But the here,i cursor count is always showing 0.I don't know what is the problem.I have searched a lot but am not able to figure it out.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search messages from a particular number, you can try this code.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String where = "address="+ phNum; //here you can use that particular number
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id"}, where, null,null);
```

It has worked for me. let me know if it solved your issue.